# How to change the level of Table Of Contents in plone?

Tags: plone

**How can I can customize the number of levels shown in a Table Of Contents in plone?**

Plone shows by default three levels in the TOC (from H2 to H4). How can I customize it to show more than three? I couldn't find the code that generates the TOC anywhere

Comment: The code is clientside, at least up to 4.3.2, and found in `Products/CMFPlone/skins/plone_ecmascript/toc.js`. Happy customizing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ulrich is correct, the TOC is generated in the browser by the toc.js script.  If you have access to the ZMI, you can find it in `portal_skins/plone_ecmascript/toc.js` and from there you can make a copy of it in the `custom` folder.

The depth is limited in line 19:

```
    $(content).find('*').not('.comment > h3').filter(function() { return (/^h[1234]$/).test(this.tagName.toLowerCase()); })
```

You can just add a 5 (and even a 6) to the `regex`, and that might be all there is to it.